Characterization of the projection in a Hilbert space.
I have to prove that two variational problems are equivalent.
Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $K \subset H$ be a nonempty closed
convex set. We know that $$y=P_K(x)\iff \begin{cases}\tag 1
  y\in K \\
  \Re\langle x-y, v-y\rangle\le 0\quad \forall v\in K  
\end{cases}$$
Where $P_K(x)$ denotes the projection of $x$ onto $K$.
Now, I must prove that if $M$ be a nonempty closed subspace of $H$ then results that   $$y=P_M(x) \iff \begin{cases}\tag2
  y\in M \\
  \langle x-y, z\rangle= 0\quad \forall z\in M  
\end{cases}$$
My Attempt
It suffices to show that problems $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent when $M$ is a subspace. If $y$ is a solution of $(2)$, then $(1)$ follows taking $z=v-y$, where $v\in M.$
Conversely,suppose that $y$ satisfies $(1)$. Since $M$ is a subspace we can choose $v=y \pm z$ where $z\in M$ thus obtaining $$\Re \langle x-y, \pm z\rangle \le 0\quad \forall z\in M$$ and then $$\Re \langle x-y, z\rangle=0\quad \forall z\in M.$$ Then substituting $iz$ in place of $z$ in the last relation results that $$\Im \langle x-y, z \rangle=\Re \langle x-y, iz\rangle=0\quad\forall z\in M.$$ Therefore $$\langle x-y,z \rangle=0$$
for all $z\in M$.

Is this procedure correct?

